# Правописание слова непроросший

Tags: орфография

Как пишется слово (не)проросший? Вроде можно заменить синонимом. Или здесь подчеркивается отрицание?

Предложение: *В нормальном, (не)проросшем, картофеле содержание крахмала составляет 14-15 %.*

Comment: Можно предложение целиком? Тут или "в нормальном непроросшем картофеле", или "в нормальном, а не проросшем, картофеле". Приведённый пример - нечто среднее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше напишем слитно и с обособлением: В нормальном, **непроросшем**, картофеле содержание крахмала составляет 14-15 %.

В данном случае мы имеем дело **с пояснением**, сравнить: В нормальном, то есть непроросшем, картофеле...  При пояснении такого вида подбирается второе слово с тем же содержанием, но более понятное для окружающих: нормальный картофель  – это непроросший картофель.

**Нет здесь отрицания с противопоставлением** (даже скрытым), подобные конструкции пишутся с запятой, например: "Разве нормальный, а не безумный человек может смотреть это по телевизору каждый день."

Answer (score 1):

И то и другое написания  возможны, зависит от Вашего понимания смысла.  Мне ближе слитное написание.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу такие варианты:
1) В нормальном непроросшем картофеле... Слитно, так как полное причастие без пояснительных слов; но и запятая тогда не нужна - причастие же перед существительным; первая запятая тоже нелогична - перечисляются неоднородные определения;
2) В нормальном, не проросшем, картофеле... Раздельно, так как подразумевается противопоставление; тогда и запятая нужна - причастие в качестве уточняющего слова.